# Custom field not being found in trigger

Tags: apex, custom-field, developer-console

I'm attempting to add a trigger that updates a field based on the value of another field, namely Total. So I define a `trigger`:

```
trigger TotalTriggerAccount on Total (after update) {
}
```

the developer console reports `Invalid type: Schema.Total`

So then I change the custom field to match the DB column name:

```
trigger TotalTriggerAccount on Total__c (after update) {
}
```

the developer console reports `Invalid type: Schema.Total__c`

The field is set up on the Account as:

[image]

And I can view the `total` on the `Details` tab of a `test account` I created:

[image]

How to enable the `TotalTriggerAccount` to have visibility on the custom field `Total__c` ?

Comment: you can't create a trigger for **field**. A trigger is created for an **object**. I recommend reading and complete the trailhead [apex triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers)

Answer (score 0):

From reading the trailhead [apex triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers) I use:

```
trigger TotalTriggerAccount on Account (after update) {
```